# My Android Google Map can't load with all setup being accomplished, please check it out

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have check all settings, but it can't load the map with fragment but a zoom widget. It have no gridding. I have check the key but don't think it has any problem.
Below is my code.

manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <!-- TODO: Replace "com.example.hellomap" with your package name -->
    <permission
            android:name="com.example.hellomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.hellomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- The following four permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyDQFrrAorDIMec2q4kcxO9Y4hanG8x1YI0"/>

        <activity
                android:name="MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

code:
    package com.example.hellomap;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements InfoWindowAdapter{
private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: any error is come in logcat..............

Comment: some error like Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings And Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES in package com.google.android.ears and so on.

Comment: have a konw how to use github project i have posted google map example on github

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/GoogleMapExample

Comment: sorry I'm a new guy about this and don't how to use it

Comment: I will have a try to use it

Comment: write <meta-tag /> outside the <application /> tag

Comment: I don't think so, because The official document say "add the following declaration within the <application> element".

Comment: if you are running this on emulator, make sure it's connected to the internet, open browser app inside the emulator and navigate to any website ...

Comment: Yeah, I uses a genymotion emulator, it can connect to the internet. But the map doesn't load any way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have activated android map v2 api on google console.
you have created proper android key by entering correct SHA1 and package name on google console.
try to run it on physical device.

Comment: yeah, I have double checked it, now the only way I haven't tried is testing it in a physical device because my company doesn't allow connecting computer with mobile devices.

Comment: google play services must be there in a device for a map. You have to run it on physical device as google play service will be running in background in that device.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "Google Repository" installed from the SDK manager. They never mention this in the instructions but this must be installed alongside the Google Play Services SDK for everything to function.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have solved the problem. It was caused by network.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm in China, it's not convenient to access Google server. Therefore I used a proxy to make the network can access the Google and then everything goes well. Thank all you guys for responding and special thank to @Yazan who gave me a prompt.